# Does giving food to my christian maid please Allah or not?

Tags: food, sadaqah, ahlul-kitab

I have a maid who is christian by faith. She is poor. I often give her food for her children and family, so that it provides her a little ease financially, and she doesn't have to cook after getting home after a day of work. I do this in order to please Allah.

But I am confused about whether my deed will please Allah and earn me reward or not (God forbid). Please guide me. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> “And they (the righteous) are those who give food – in spite of their own need, to the needy, and the orphan, and the captive, [saying in their hearts], '*We only feed you for the sake of God, and we desire nothing in return from you, not even a word of thanks*'”  (Surah Al-Insaan: 8-9).

We find in the Surah Al-Muddaththir a dialogue between the denizens of Jahannam and the dwellers of Jannat who are asking them, what was it that led them to hell?

> “What has brought you to this burning abode? They will answer, ‘*We were not amongst those who worshipped God (out of arrogance) and nor did we feed the needy….*’” (Surah Al-Muddaththir: 42-44)

The Prophet Muhammad SAW said: >"Feed the hungry, visit the sick and set free the captives." (Sahih Bukhari, Volume 7, Hadith 552)

> "Beware!  Whoever is cruel and hard on a non-Muslim minority, curtails their rights, burdens them with more than they can bear, or takes anything from them against their free will; I (Prophet Muhammad) will complain against the person on the Day of Judgment." 
>    (Abu Dawud)

Please note that neither Allah, the Cherisher of mankind, nor the Prophet Muhammad SAW has forbidden in their orders to feed the non-muslims. There is a hadith describing how we should behave with the Kafir captives. I can't precisely recall that right now, but it goes like this: The Sahabis (followers) were ordered to feed the Kafir captives, let them ride on camels while they are guiding the camels, let the Kafir captives teach the Muslims and set them free after a certain time.

Comment: Jazak Allah khair

Answer (score 2):

Inshallah it will. According to most schools of thought, giving non-obligatory Sadaqah to non-Muslims is permitted, among the evidence for which is the verse of the Quran that describes the traits of the righteous as:

> ويطعمون الطعام على حبه مسكينا ويتيما و**أسيرا**
>
> And they give food in spite of love for it to the needy, the orphan, and the **captive**,
>
> <sup>— [Quran 76:8](http://quran.com/76/8)</sup>

Captives at that time were polytheist prisoners of war, see [Tafsir al-Jassas](https://shamela.ws/book/23579/1916) etc.

Further there is the hadith which describes a person being rewarded for giving water to a thirsty dog, where the Prophet ﷺ said:

> في كل ذات كبد رطبة أجر
>
> There is a reward for serving any animate (living being).
>
> <sup>— [Sahih Bukhari , كتاب الأدب](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/78/40)</sup>

Additionally there are narrations about [Asma bint Abu Bakr](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/78/9) and [Umar ibn Al-Khattab](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/51/45) giving to their non-Muslim relatives.

**Reference:**

- [المغني لابن قدامة](https://shamela.ws/book/8463/940#p1)

Comment: Jazak Allah khair